# Meteor + Materialize: collapsable in for each doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, collapsable, materialize

I have a collapsable (materialize) whose elements are created from a `for each`, however the "dropdown" doesn't work. Everything that isn't in the `for each` works.

How can I fix this problem?

jobList.html

```
<template name="jobList">
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    {{#each jobs}}
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header">{{title}}</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>{{description}}</p></div>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

jobList.js

```
Template.jobList.rendered = function () {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        accordion: false
    });
};

Template.jobList.helpers({
    jobs: function() {
        return Jobs.find();
    }
});
```

The template `jobList` is in another template that does nothing appart from having `{{> jobList}}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is relative to DOM readiness, at the time you're executing the jQuery plugin initialization, the `{{#each}}` loop has not yet rendered HTML elements.

What you can do to solve this problem is defining a separate function to return the cursor you want to iterate over, and observe this cursor inside an `autorun` inside the `onRendered` callback of your template.

When we detect the cursor count is modified, it means a document has been added (in particular when the subscription is ready and the initial set of documents made their way to the client) or removed, and we have to re-run the jQuery plugin initialization.

It's important to wait for every other current invalidated computations to finish before running the jQuery initialization, this is why we need to use `Tracker.afterFlush` (we can't predict in which order invalidated computations are re-run, we can only execute code after this process is done).

That's because the helper returning our cursor is a computation too and will be invalidated when a document is added or removed, thus inserting or removing the corresponding DOM subset : it is then vital to execute our jQuery plugin initialization after DOM manipulation is done.

```
function jobsCursor(){
  return Jobs.find();
}

Template.jobsList.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
    // registers a dependency on the number of documents returned by the cursor
    var jobsCount = jobsCursor().count();
    // this will log 0 at first, then after the jobs publication is ready
    // it will log the total number of documents published
    console.log(jobsCount);
    // initialize the plugin only when Blaze is done with DOM manipulation
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      this.$(".collapsible").collapsible({
        accordion: false
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
});

Template.jobsList.helpers({
  jobs:jobsCursor
});
```